# Characterization for normality

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let  $X$  be  a  topological normal space. Let  one-point  sets  in  $X$  be closed. I   want   to  prove  that if  given  a  closed   set  $A$   and  an  open  set  $U$  containing  $A$,  there  is   an  open set  $V$  containing $A$   such   that $\overline{V}$ $\subset$ $U$.
My  idea  is  that:  Let  $F = U^C$.  Then  $F$  is  closed so  using  that  $X$  is  a  normal  space  there  exists  $M$  and  $N$  open  sets  such  that $F \subset M $, $ A \subset N$  and  $M \cap N =  \emptyset$.  I  suppose  $ V = N$  but  I  can't  to  prove  or to  dispove  that.

Answer (score 1):

$A^C$ is not necessarily closed here; $A$ is a **closed set**, not necessarily an open one.

Instead, take $F = U^C$.  Then $F$ and $A$ are two closed subsets of $X$, and so there are open sets $M,N$ with $F \subset M$, $A \subset N$ and $M \cap N = \emptyset$.  In other words, we have
$$
A \subset N\subset M^C\subset U
$$
Notably, $M^C$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry  for  that  mistake!

Comment: No need to apologize. Glad to help